# What can block network connections

Tags: linux, fedora, python3

I'm trying to create mqtt connection using python. The shortest code to reproduce the problem is

```
import paho.mqtt.client as paho

client = paho.Client('myClient')
client.username_pw_set('user', 'password')
client.connect('my.broker.com')
```

On the last line I get

```
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

Interesting that connection is not refused by server. `connect()` has logging and it seems that connection is refused before the actual request.

I tried the script on Windows machine and it works fine as well as on Ubuntu, but I need to run it on the machine with Fedora 37 (which refuses the connection). I believe there is some misconfiguration, but I have basic Linux knowledge and don't know where I can look to find it. I don't know current states of both Linuxes, they may be set up somehow, but Windows machine have pretty default settings. I have googled and saw some recomendations like:

- Run local mqtt broker (not suitable for me as I have to connect to the remote broker)
- Check the firewall rules (I believe there is no firewall in the network, as other machines can connect to the broker)
- Check iptables (it shows no filtering rules)

Are there any suggestions on what else I can check? Are there any Fedora-specific or Linux-wide restrictions on socket creation?

Comment: Can you ping (name resolving and a response) for `my.broker.com`? If the server is listening on port 12345, can you `nc -vvv my broker.com 12345` and get a `Connected!` response?

Comment: ```ping``` shows ```100% packet loss```. ```nc``` shows connection refused.

Comment: Does ping resolve the name to the correct IP address?

Comment: Yes. What can be the issue in that case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unix-wide:

Normally only root can use ports numbered 1023 or less, but since MQTT default port number is 1883, that should not be a problem.

Fedora-specific:

Fedora uses SELinux by default, but that should not restrict interactive sessions of regular users in ways that would apply here. But if you are running your script through some service (e.g. as a webserver CGI script or something), your script might be prevented from opening outgoing network connections unless SELinux is configured to allow it.

Basic connectivity testing:

If you have `telnet` or netcat (`nc`) installed, test connectivity with:

```
telnet my.broker.com 1883
```

or

```
nc -v my.broker.com 1883
```

respectively.

If you have `traceroute` installed, run a **TCP** traceroute **on the specific  port your application needs** (1883 is the default for MQTT with no SSL/TLS):

```
sudo traceroute -T -p 1883 my.broker.com
```

If a basic TCP connection to the broker can be successfully established, both `telnet` and `nc` will explicitly tell you so.

If something on the network is dropping the connection attempt, `traceroute -T` should help you identify that thing.

Comment: Have no telnet, but ```nc my.broker.com 1883``` returned ```Ncat: Connection refused``` even with ```sudo```. What does it mean? Traceroute, seems show no errors. It resolves ip address of the broker.

Comment: It means either `my.broker.com` or some firewall actively rejected the connection. If you  are sure the broker is running and listening on TCP port 1883, then there must be a software or hardware firewall filtering the traffic at some point. If the last line of `traceroute` showed the address of `my.broker.com` and sensible round-trip times (and no error annotations like `!X` for example), then the filtering must happen on the `my.broker.com` system. Note that modern Linux systems may be using netfilter instead of iptables (run `nft list ruleset` as root/with sudo to see if configured).

Comment: Yes, I'm sure about the brocker. Other machines can connect to the same brocker using the same commands (and yes, ```connect()``` has the second optional argument ```port``` which defaults to ```1883```). ```traceroute``` shows correct ipaddress, time about 0.2 ms, and no !X annotations. This Fedora have no nft installed. How can I check SELinux settings?

Comment: `sestatus` or `getenforce` should indicate if SELinux is enabled in enforcing mode. Actual configuration of SELinux is however not exactly a small topic.

Comment: ```$ getenforce

Enforcing```

Yeah. SELinux is very difficult to configure. Tried to choose the simple way - to disable it - but it does not help. Seems, that you are right. And the only possible reason is some device somewhere in the network. Thank you very much!